# Palabra para hacer una referencia a una grosería con otra palabra

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, sinónimos

Se que existe una palabra para hacer referencia a una grosería diciendo otra palabra.
Por ejemplo,

Yo pensé que tusa era **palabra que no recuerdo** de vagina.

No recuerdo esa palabra.

Comment: Si, es eufemismo. Gracias. Si gustas puedes responder para que te acepte tu respuesta como correcta.

Comment: eufemismo no sería otra grosería. Es una palabra menos fuerte, que evita ser grosero/a.

Answer (score 2):

La palabra que estaba buscando es: **Eufemismo**